# Keras VGG16 with flow_from_directory val_acc not rising

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I use keras and import VGG16 network with imagenet weights to classify male/female photos.

Strcture of directories is:

- split_1/train/male/*.jpg
- split_1/train/female/*.jpg
- split_1/val/female/*.jpg
- split_1/val/male/*.jpg

I tried most of the solutions I found over the internet but none of them worked:

- changing `batch_size`
- changing optimizers
- changing `class_mode`/loss function
- setting every layer to `trainable`
- copying every layer from VGG to my sequential

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications

[...]

img_width, img_height = 224, 224

top_model_weights_path = "%s_retry2.h5" % split
train_data_dir = "%s/train" % split
validation_data_dir = "%s/val" % split
batch_size = 48
nb_train_samples = 4000
nb_validation_samples = ( 299 // batch_size ) * batch_size
epochs = 5

def train_top_model():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        horizontal_flip=True,
        shear_range=0.2,
        rescale=1. / 255)

    vdatagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    traingen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        follow_links=True,
        shuffle=True)

     valgen = vdatagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        follow_links=True,
        shuffle=True)

    vgg_model = applications.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(vgg_model)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit_generator(traingen,
              epochs=epochs,
              steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
              validation_data=valgen,
              validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

It reports actual amount of images so it finds the jpgs properly.
Accuracy in val keeps being "random" and the same (~50%) during entire training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the learning rate, it may be the case where your model is overshooting the minima every time and hence not able to converge.

If any kind of hyper parameter tuning doesn't work then you need to fix your data but i think male/female classification data shouldn't be that tough to learn for a CNN model with pre-trained weights.

Comment: Thank you, I think now it's working, with `RMSprop(lr=0.0001)`

Answer (score 0):

How Many sample do you have per class???
It seems that you don't have enough data to fine tune these large scale parameters that VGG16 has. (138 million if you trainable all the layers)

I suggest :
1. for gender classification problem, Try to use an official dataset such as IMDB-WIKI 
2. If you wanna use your own data first collect more label sample and after that augment all of them
3. finally, Use state of the art CNN architectures such as Xception (you can load imagenet pre-traind of xception in keras) freeze 20 first layers and fune tune others